# How can I tell where I checked out this working copy?

Tags: svn

I have a subversion working copy checked out into the directory `my-project/`.

I check out with `svn checkout URL`

I want to find URL after having checked out. Is there a command I can run in that working copy directory to find out who it is checked out as?

I want to use the command-line SVN client, not a GUI program specific to any OS.

If it is possible, I would like to get the original checkout-command. But if this is not possible, I would like to get the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you says about `svn info` ?
This command is shows your URL, working copy path, revision number and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `svn info` inside your working directory to get the URL and various other repository information;

```
$ svn info
Path: .
URL: http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before you can use

```
svn info .
```

on your commandline client. On TortoiseSVN I use the **switch** command showing you as default your URL. You can enable  in windows explorer(only win2k and XP) a special column "short URL" which shows you the information as well